# How can I filter my FaceBook news feed to a specific application?

Tags: facebook, news-feed

For example, suppose I wanted to see all the recent news-feed entries for mafia wars. Is there a way to filter your feed down to a specific application?

I can do this using the Facebook iPhone app client, but haven't figured out a way to do it in the browser interface to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible. There is chatter in the [Facebook Support Community](http://www.facebook.com/help/?section=community) but nothing to suggest that it is a feature right now.

There was a time where you could at least have priority of the filters by dragging but that seems to have been removed in the redesign.

For now until Facebook brings it back , you are going to be stuck with a add-on like [Feed Filter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/47397/) or just stick those people you know use mafia wars into a [Friend List](http://www.facebook.com/friends/) .

Comment: I do have a friend list for mafia wars already. is there a way to filter the newsfeed to just items from a single friend list?

Comment: @JohnFx not exactly you can get the feed of your friend list, on the left click Friends then click your relative Mafia Friend List

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to read News Feed items in your feed reader of choice, you can follow [these instructions](http://www.kristi-barrow.com/facebook-rss-feeds-what-is-available/) to build RSS feed URLs. You could then pipe the "News Feed" feed through something like [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) or [FeedRinse](http://www.feedrinse.com/) to filter out/only the applications you're interested in.

A bit of a struggle, but it should work for you.

Comment: I would be glad if could show us how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194328/facebook-graph-api-and-yahoo-pipes-getting-news-feed The closest you can get is the status feed not the news feed

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to dive into the Facebook API and do some coding then the answer is currently 'no'.